# VB Rename Folder to DATE_TIME

Tags: vb.net, date

I want to rename a folder to the current date and time using VB.NET

```
Dim thisDate As Date
thisDate = Today
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(Destination, "Backup_" &    Today)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  this:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Source) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Destination) Then
        MsgBox("Source and Destination cant be empty")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Source, Destination, True)

    Dim DestinationBackup As String = "C:\temp"
    Dim NewDir As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationBackup, "Backup_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffff"))
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(NewDir) Then
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(NewDir, True)
    End If

    System.IO.Directory.Move(Destination, NewDir)

End Sub
```

Comment: But the variable today is'nt the date & time

Comment: Okay, i tryed it, but i got this error: The Argument newName shoud be a Name and not a relative/absolute path

Comment: Destination = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

        MsgBox("Das tool wird sie benachrichtigen, wann das Backup fertiggestellt wurde!")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Source, Destination, True)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(Destination, "Backup_" & DateTime.Now)
        MsgBox("Backup wurde fertiggestellt!")

Comment: Destination must contain a complete path of directory, look my modified code

Comment: Destination is a Variable, that will be defined by starting the programm

Comment: Okay so now it tells me that the path format isnt supportet.

Here is my full Code. http://pastebin.com/raw/uaasFpUy

Comment: what containt source and destination variables when you click on button3?

Comment: usuelly your code must have a test in button3click like this      If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Source) OrElse  String.IsNullOrEmpty(Destination)  Then
         Exit sub      End if

Comment: i didnt get it :O

Comment: Your variables "Source" and "Destination" in the "Button3_Click" depend on their initialization in functions "Button1_Click" function and "Button2_Click". These variables must be tested to check whether they are empty or not before doing anything with.

Comment: i have modified your button3_click function in my code ;)

Comment: so this works on your pc? i got another error message: "A part of the path cannot be found".

Comment: yes :) Have you modify the path into DestinationBackup  variable?

Comment: what path should that be?

Comment: should i add a temp folder to my c drive?

Comment: A directory where you want to store the backup. Already trying to "c: \ temp"

Comment: Yes it works now :) i made another command that create a Backup folder on start of the form :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
date.now().tostring("yyyyMMdd")
```